# Amazon S3 REST library : how to get a link to a ressource that nevers expires?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

To retrieve a url for a ressource on a bucket i use :

```
S3Object.url_for('beluga_baby.jpg', 'marcel_molina')
```

By default links expires after 5 minutes. **Is it possible to ask for a link that never expires ?**

I think i could set an expiration date far in the future but it seems kind of ugly...

```
doomsday = Time.mktime(2038, 1, 18).to_i
S3Object.url_for('beluga_baby.jpg',
                   'marcel',
                   :expires => doomsday)
```

P.S: I use the ruby library but i guess the question applies to all languages(?)

Thanks for your help,
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a link that never expires for private files.

Your solution of setting a far future expiry date is the correct way to do this.